# Does kill -3 actually terminate a java process? Or just generate a thread dump?

Tags: linux, centos, java, pid

CentOS 5.9

If I run `kill -3 <java process pid>` what actually happens?  As per [this red hat article](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/18178), I understand that a Java Thread Dump is generated but is the process terminated? It doesn't appear to be based on my tests:

```
[root@foobox ~]# kill -3 14559

[root@foobox ~]# service foo status
foo (pid 14559) is running...
```

In other words: could I collect a thread dump via this manner without impacting the service?

Comment: Yes, you could.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully, `kill -3` doesn't terminate the JVM process.

A thread dump is very slightly impacting the service during the stacktrace collection, especially if thousands of threads are running.

Note that if the `-Xrs` flag is used, the JVM no more specifically handle the `SIGQUIT` signal and then that signal will likely terminate the process unless a alternate handler is in place in some native code.

Answer (score 5):

https://superuser.com/questions/352147/what-does-kill-3-mean may provide with you some more information.

It's up to the process to determine how exactly it's going to react when it receives `SIGQUIT`

Since that signal can be caught, ignored, or blocked by the process it may not respect the `kill`. If you want like to peer even closer I suggest stack tracing the PID with `strace` while sending it `SIGQUIT` with kill.